# Unable to launch iOS device using appium desktop 1.6.4

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to automate an iOS mobile app using appium desktop 1.6.4 in mac. i am using real device for that. I have given all desired capabilities . But when i am trying to start session, it is throwing below error.

> Could not initialize ios-deploy make sure it is installed (npm install
>   -g ios-deploy) and works on your system

I have installed iOS-deploy also. Please find the screenshot attached

[image]

[image: .]

Please help me on this.

Comment: By looking at the installation directory, i think iOS-deploy is getting installed in different directory.Any help will be appreciated